Kotlin databinding for a custom view (canvas) for a recyclerview with multiple viewtypes
Previously I used kotlin synthetics, but now I'm trying to upgrade to data binding.
I have a recyclerview in a fragment and it will have multiple view types all of which will be custom-draw with a canvas.
Here is some of my code:
open class EtaRecyclerViewData {
    data class OnDutyHeaderMain(
        val leg:Int,
        val shift:Int,
        val startTime: String?,
    ) : EtaRecyclerViewData()

    data class OnDutyHeaderLocation(
        val leg:Int,
        val shift:Int,
        var city: String,
        var state: String,
        var country: String
    ) : EtaRecyclerViewData()

    data class OnDutyHeaderBottom(
        val leg:Int,
        val shift:Int
    ):EtaRecyclerViewData()

    data class SegmentDriving(
        val leg:Int,
        val shift:Int,
        val segment: Int,
        val startTime: String?
    ):EtaRecyclerViewData()
}

The recyclerviewadapter:
val itemList = arrayListOf<Any>()
private const val TYPE_ON_DUTY_HEADER_MAIN = 0
private const val TYPE_ON_DUTY_HEADER_LOCATION = 1
private const val TYPE_ON_DUTY_HEADER_BOTTOM = 2
private const val TYPE_SEGMENT_DRIVING = 3

class ChatDiffUtil(private var oldList: List<Any>, private var newList: List<Any>) : DiffUtil.Callback() {
    override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
        return oldList.size
    }

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
        return newList.size
    }

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]
    }
}

class EtaRecyclerViewAdapter(private val cellClickListener: CellClickListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class OnDutyHeaderMain(private val onDutyHeaderMainBinding: OnDutyHeaderMainBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(onDutyHeaderMainBinding.root) {
        fun bind(segmentData: EtaRecyclerViewData.OnDutyHeaderMain) {
            onDutyHeaderMainBinding.startTimeText = segmentData

            onDutyHeaderMainBinding.locationBtn.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d(LogTag, "class OnDutyHeaderMain->fun bind->Click locationBtn")
                cellClickListener.onDutyHeaderMainLocationClickListener(segmentData)
            }
        }
    }

    inner class OnDutyHeaderLocation(private val onDutyHeaderLocationBinding: OnDutyHeaderLocationBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(onDutyHeaderLocationBinding.root) {
        fun bind(segmentData: EtaRecyclerViewData.OnDutyHeaderLocation) {
            onDutyHeaderLocationBinding.startTimeText = segmentData
            Log.d(LogTag, "class OnDutyHeaderLocation->fun bind: segmentData=$segmentData")
            // TODO: Click listeners
        }
    }

    inner class OnDutyHeaderBottom(private val onDutyHeaderBottomBinding: OnDutyHeaderBottomBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(onDutyHeaderBottomBinding.root) {
        fun bind(segmentData: EtaRecyclerViewData.OnDutyHeaderBottom) {
            onDutyHeaderBottomBinding.headerBottom = segmentData

            onDutyHeaderBottomBinding.showSegmentsBtn.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d(LogTag, "EtaRecyclerViewAdapter-> class OnDutyHeaderBottom->fun bind->Click")
                cellClickListener.onDutyHeaderBottomClickListener(segmentData)
            }
        }
    }

    inner class SegmentDriving(private val segmentDrivingBinding: SegmentDrivingBinding):
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(segmentDrivingBinding.root) {
        fun bind(segmentData: EtaRecyclerViewData.SegmentDriving) {
            segmentDrivingBinding.startTimeText = segmentData

            segmentDrivingBinding.startTimeTextView.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d(LogTag, "class SegmentOnDutyViewHolder->fun bind->Click")
                cellClickListener.segmentDrivingClickListener(segmentData)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            TYPE_ON_DUTY_HEADER_MAIN -> OnDutyHeaderMain(
                OnDutyHeaderMainBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )

            TYPE_ON_DUTY_HEADER_LOCATION -> OnDutyHeaderLocation(
                OnDutyHeaderLocationBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )

            TYPE_ON_DUTY_HEADER_BOTTOM -> OnDutyHeaderBottom(
                OnDutyHeaderBottomBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )

            TYPE_SEGMENT_DRIVING -> SegmentDriving(
                SegmentDrivingBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid ViewType")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is OnDutyHeaderMain -> holder.bind(itemList[position] as EtaRecyclerViewData.OnDutyHeaderMain)
            is OnDutyHeaderLocation -> holder.bind(itemList[position] as EtaRecyclerViewData.OnDutyHeaderLocation)
            is OnDutyHeaderBottom -> holder.bind(itemList[position] as EtaRecyclerViewData.OnDutyHeaderBottom)
            is SegmentDriving -> holder.bind(itemList[position] as EtaRecyclerViewData.SegmentDriving)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = itemList.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (itemList[position]) {
            is EtaRecyclerViewData.OnDutyHeaderMain -> TYPE_ON_DUTY_HEADER_MAIN
            is EtaRecyclerViewData.OnDutyHeaderLocation -> TYPE_ON_DUTY_HEADER_LOCATION
            is EtaRecyclerViewData.OnDutyHeaderBottom -> TYPE_ON_DUTY_HEADER_BOTTOM
            is EtaRecyclerViewData.SegmentDriving -> TYPE_SEGMENT_DRIVING
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Item")
        }
    }
}

The customview:
package com.example.otrt.ui.home

class OnDutyHeaderLocation @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr),GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    val Float.toPx get() = this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density
    val Double.toStandardAngle get() = if (this + 90 > 360) this - 270 else this + 90.0
    private val typeface =
        Typeface.create(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.latoregular), 500, false)

    private val logTag = "DrivingCard"
    private var gDetector: GestureDetectorCompat
    var areaClicked: String = "null"
    private val locationText = LocationText()

    private inner class LocationText {
        var left = 0f
            private set
        var top = 0f
            private set
        var right = 0f
            private set
        var bottom = 0f
            private set

        //Public variables
        var city = "Some City"
        var state = "Some State"
        var country = "Some Country"

        // Colors
        var displaytextColor = Color.BLACK

        // Paints

        // Paths

        // Information
        private val cityDisplay = TextDisplay()
        private val stateDisplay = TextDisplay()
        private val countryDisplay = TextDisplay()

        //Click Areas
        val cityClickArea = Rect()
        val stateClickArea = Rect()
        val countryClickArea = Rect()

        fun measure(
            leftSide: Float,
            topSide: Float,
            rightSide: Float,
            bottomSide: Float
        ) {
            Log.d("DrivingCard-TopTab", "DrivingCard-TopTab:Measure")

            left = leftSide
            top = topSide
            right = rightSide
            bottom = bottomSide

            with(cityDisplay) {
                val bounds = RectF(
                    left,
                    top,
                    (right - left / 2) + left,
                    ((bottom - top) * .7f) + top
                )
                halign = "LEFT"
                vAlign = "TOP"
                text = city
                textColor = displaytextColor
                set(bounds, 0f.toPx, 0f.toPx)
                cityClickArea.set(bounds.toRect())
            }

            with(stateDisplay) {
                val bounds = RectF(
                    left,
                    ((bottom - top) * .7f) + top,
                    (right - left / 2) + left,
                    bottom
                )
                halign = "LEFT"
                vAlign = "CENTER"
                text = state
                textColor = displaytextColor
                set(bounds, 0f.toPx, 0f.toPx)
                stateClickArea.set(bounds.toRect())
            }

            with(countryDisplay) {
                val bounds = RectF(
                    left,
                    ((bottom - top) * .7f) + top,
                    right,
                    bottom
                )
                halign = "RIGHT"
                vAlign = "CENTER"
                text = country
                textColor = displaytextColor
                set(bounds, 5f.toPx, 0f.toPx)
                countryClickArea.set(bounds.toRect())
            }
        }

        fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
            Log.d(logTag, "OnDutyHeaderLocation->class LocationText->fun draw:Draw")

            cityDisplay.draw(canvas)
            stateDisplay.draw(canvas)
            countryDisplay.draw(canvas)
        }
    }

    init {
        setupAttributes(attrs)
        this.gDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(context, this)
        gDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this)
    }

    private fun setupAttributes(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        val typedArray =
            context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.OnDutyHeaderLocation, 0, 0)
            val cityLocation = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.OnDutyHeaderLocation_cityLocation)

            if(!isInEditMode) {
                typedArray.recycle()
            }
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        val widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)

        val totalWidth = widthSize.toFloat()
        val totalHeight = 40f.toPx
        val bottomPadding = 5f.toPx
        val outLineStroke = 1f.toPx

        locationText.measure(
            5f.toPx,
            5f.toPx,
            totalWidth,
            totalHeight
        )

        setMeasuredDimension(totalWidth.toInt(), totalHeight.toInt() + bottomPadding.toInt())
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        locationText.draw(canvas)
    }

    fun update() {
        //newTopTab.update()
    }

    fun areaClicked(): String {
        return areaClicked
    }

    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onShowPress(e: MotionEvent) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onScroll(
        e1: MotionEvent?,
        e2: MotionEvent,
        distanceX: Float,
        distanceY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onFling(
        e1: MotionEvent?,
        e2: MotionEvent,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onDoubleTapEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}

the layout for the custom view:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="startTimeText"
            type="com.example.otrt.ui.home.EtaRecyclerViewData.OnDutyHeaderLocation" />
    </data>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <com.example.otrt.ui.home.OnDutyHeaderLocation
            android:id="@+id/onDutyHeaderLocation_canvas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cityLocation="Test"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>

The attributes for the custom view:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="OnDutyHeaderLocation">
        <attr name="cityLocation" format="string" />
        <attr name="stateLocation" format="string" />
        <attr name="countryLocation" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>

I got the databinding working just fine on 'normal' views, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with the custom stuff. I can't really find any examples online comparable to my situation.
Anything that help point me in the right direction is appreciated. I'm kind of swimming around here with little actual understanding of what I need to do.
I believe I have solved this problem...here is what I did to get it working:
Modified my EtaRecyclerViewAdapter:
inner class OnDutyHeaderLocation(private val onDutyHeaderLocationBinding: OnDutyHeaderLocationBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(onDutyHeaderLocationBinding.root) {
    fun bind(segmentData: EtaRecyclerViewData.OnDutyHeaderLocation) {
        onDutyHeaderLocationBinding.item = segmentData // Set the data object for binding
        onDutyHeaderLocationBinding.executePendingBindings() // Force immediate binding
        Log.d(LogTag, "class OnDutyHeaderLocation->fun bind: segmentData=$segmentData")
        // TODO: Click listeners
    }
}

Modified on_duty_header_location:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.example.otrt.ui.home.EtaRecyclerViewData.OnDutyHeaderLocation" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <com.example.otrt.ui.home.OnDutyHeaderLocation
            android:id="@+id/onDutyHeaderLocation_canvas"
            app:cityInfo="@{item.cityInfo}"
            app:stateInfo="@{item.stateInfo}"
            app:countryInfo="@{item.countryInfo}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>

Added this BindingAdapter to my OnDutyHeaderLocation.kt file (this could go anywhere really since it's not actually IN the class, but I put it here because it's for this class only)
    @BindingAdapter("cityInfo", "stateInfo", "countryInfo", requireAll = false)
fun setLocationInfo(
view: OnDutyHeaderLocation,
cityInfo: String?,
stateInfo: String?,
countryInfo: String?
) {
    view.cityInfo = cityInfo
    view.stateInfo = stateInfo
    view.countryInfo = countryInfo
}

And finally, I added this in the OnDutyHeaderLocation class:
var cityInfo: String? = "Default City"
    set(value) {
        field = value
        invalidate()
    }
var stateInfo: String? = "XX"
    set(value) {
        field = value
        invalidate()
    }
var countryInfo: String? = "Default Country"
    set(value) {
        field = value
        invalidate()
    }

Here is the whole custom view class now:
    package com.example.otrt.ui.home

import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat
import androidx.core.graphics.toRect
import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import com.example.otrt.R

@BindingAdapter("cityInfo", "stateInfo", "countryInfo", requireAll = false)
fun setLocationInfo(
view: OnDutyHeaderLocation,
cityInfo: String?,
stateInfo: String?,
countryInfo: String?
) {
    view.cityInfo = cityInfo
    view.stateInfo = stateInfo
    view.countryInfo = countryInfo
}

class OnDutyHeaderLocation @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr),GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    val Float.toPx get() = this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density
    val Double.toStandardAngle get() = if (this + 90 > 360) this - 270 else this + 90.0
    private val typeface =
        Typeface.create(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.latoregular), 500, false)

    private val logTag = "DrivingCard"
    private var gDetector: GestureDetectorCompat
    var areaClicked: String = "null"
    private val locationText = LocationText()

    var cityInfo: String? = "Default City"
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }
    var stateInfo: String? = "XX"
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }
    var countryInfo: String? = "Default Country"
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }

    private inner class LocationText {
        var left = 0f
            private set
        var top = 0f
            private set
        var right = 0f
            private set
        var bottom = 0f
            private set

        // Colors
        var displaytextColor = Color.BLACK

        // Paints

        // Paths

        // Information
        private val cityDisplay = TextDisplay()
        private val stateDisplay = TextDisplay()
        private val countryDisplay = TextDisplay()

        //Click Areas
        val cityClickArea = Rect()
        val stateClickArea = Rect()
        val countryClickArea = Rect()

        fun measure(
            leftSide: Float,
            topSide: Float,
            rightSide: Float,
            bottomSide: Float
        ) {
            Log.d("DrivingCard-TopTab", "DrivingCard-TopTab:Measure")

            left = leftSide
            top = topSide
            right = rightSide
            bottom = bottomSide

            with(cityDisplay) {
                val bounds = RectF(
                    left,
                    top,
                    (right - left / 2) + left,
                    ((bottom - top) * .7f) + top
                )
                halign = "LEFT"
                vAlign = "TOP"
                text = cityInfo
                textColor = displaytextColor
                set(bounds, 0f.toPx, 0f.toPx)
                cityClickArea.set(bounds.toRect())
            }

            with(stateDisplay) {
                val bounds = RectF(
                    left,
                    ((bottom - top) * .7f) + top,
                    (right - left / 2) + left,
                    bottom
                )
                halign = "LEFT"
                vAlign = "CENTER"
                text = stateInfo
                textColor = displaytextColor
                set(bounds, 0f.toPx, 0f.toPx)
                stateClickArea.set(bounds.toRect())
            }

            with(countryDisplay) {
                val bounds = RectF(
                    left,
                    ((bottom - top) * .7f) + top,
                    right,
                    bottom
                )
                halign = "RIGHT"
                vAlign = "CENTER"
                text = countryInfo
                textColor = displaytextColor
                set(bounds, 5f.toPx, 0f.toPx)
                countryClickArea.set(bounds.toRect())
            }
        }

        fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
            Log.d(logTag, "OnDutyHeaderLocation->class LocationText->fun draw:Draw")

            cityDisplay.draw(canvas)
            stateDisplay.draw(canvas)
            countryDisplay.draw(canvas)
        }
    }

    init {
        setupAttributes(attrs)
        this.gDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(context, this)
        gDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this)
    }

    private fun setupAttributes(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        val typedArray =
            context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.OnDutyHeaderLocation, 0, 0)
            val cityLocation = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.OnDutyHeaderLocation_cityLocation)

            if(!isInEditMode) {
                typedArray.recycle()
            }
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        val widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)

        val totalWidth = widthSize.toFloat()
        val totalHeight = 40f.toPx
        val bottomPadding = 5f.toPx
        val outLineStroke = 1f.toPx

        locationText.measure(
            5f.toPx,
            5f.toPx,
            totalWidth,
            totalHeight
        )

        setMeasuredDimension(totalWidth.toInt(), totalHeight.toInt() + bottomPadding.toInt())
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        locationText.draw(canvas)
    }

    fun update() {
        //newTopTab.update()
    }

    fun areaClicked(): String {
        return areaClicked
    }

    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onShowPress(e: MotionEvent) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onScroll(
        e1: MotionEvent?,
        e2: MotionEvent,
        distanceX: Float,
        distanceY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onFling(
        e1: MotionEvent?,
        e2: MotionEvent,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onDoubleTapEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}

Is the view being displayed normally without putting it up in recycler view?
